# Merge 2 dataframes in Pyspark

Tags: python, azure, pyspark, databricks, azure-databricks

In Pyspark, I have 2 dataframe. 1st dataframe say df1 is empty dataframe created from a schema. 2nd dataframe df2 is non-empty dataframe filled from a csv file.
Now I want to merge such that all below scenarios are covered.

1. If both dataframes contain same number if columns, merge them.
2. If 2nd dataframe contains additional columns than drop those columns
3. If 2nd dataframe conatains lesser columns then populate those column with null values.

I tried iterating through the empty dataframe columns' field property.
schema = some schema of few column

```
for field in scehma.fields:
    if field.name in df2.columns:
       final_df = df1.withColumn(field.name, df2[field.name].cast(field.dataType))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, you have an input dataframe with columns A, B and C and a reference schema with columns A, B, D. And you want your output dataframe to match this "reference" schema by dropping column C and adding a "NULL" column D.

Assuming `df_ref` is your reference dataframe and `df` is your csv file.

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F


# Adding missing columns
for col in df_ref.columns: 
    if col not in df.columns:
        df = df.withColumn(col, F.lit(None))

# select only ref's columns
df.select(df_ref.columns)
```

Comment: Thanks Steven, I have accepted your answer. I have a follow-up question though, is it possible to use the schema directly without creating the df_ref. Say, like create a new dataframe from df but only adding those columns that are present in the schema.

Comment: @GauravK You can create the schema manually, using the types `from pyspark.sql import types`. It can be stored or read from a json file.

Comment: If you don't want to create `df_ref` you replace it with `schema.fieldNames()` in for loop.
`for col in schema.fieldNames()`.

Comment: User mentioned he is creating dataframe from `schema`.So, i guess he is already having the `schema` and asking without creating dataframe he want the results.

Answer (score -1):

You can achieve the desired merge using the `join` operation in PySpark. Here's an example code snippet that covers all the scenarios you mentioned:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import lit

# Check if both dataframes have the same number of columns
if len(df1.columns) == len(df2.columns):
    # Merge the dataframes using a join operation
    final_df = df1.join(df2, on=df1.columns, how='inner')

# Check if the 2nd dataframe has additional columns
elif len(df1.columns) < len(df2.columns):
    # Drop the additional columns from the 2nd dataframe
    common_columns = set(df1.columns).intersection(df2.columns)
    final_df = df2.select(*common_columns)

# Check if the 2nd dataframe has fewer columns
elif len(df1.columns) > len(df2.columns):
    # Add null columns to the 2nd dataframe for the missing columns
    missing_columns = set(df1.columns).difference(df2.columns)
    for column in missing_columns:
        df2 = df2.withColumn(column, lit(None))

    final_df = df1.join(df2, on=df1.columns, how='inner')
```

Comment: one of the dataframe is an empty dataframe, therefore, you cannot join (specially with inner)